# How to add and enable OWIN role to a logged in user?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm using MVC 5 with OWIN authentication. When adding a role to a signed in user it won't take effect until user relogs:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Role1")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Action()
    {
        var currentUser = AuthenticationManager.User;
        var currentUserId = currentUser.Identity.GetUserId();
        var result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(currentUserId, "Role2"); //result confirms role added 

        return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction", "Controller");
    }

    // not accessible until relog
    [Authorize(Roles = "Role2")]
    public ActionResult AnotherAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

How do make role changes take effect immediately?

Comment: you can sign them out and back in, after applying the role

Comment: Thx Jonesy, that's definately working. Are there any possible drawbacks doing so?

Comment: Not that readily come to mind.  Their session expiration will be reset, but that probably isn't a problem.  Let me know if you do run across problems, this will be helpful in my future as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the AddUserToRole method does the assignment at the database level.  While this probably needs to happen also, what you need to do is refresh the current identity.

Short answer:  Cast the IPrincipal to a ClaimsPrincipal and cast the IIdentity to a ClaimsIdentity.  Then you can just add the claim.

```
 ClaimsPrincipal currentPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)this.User;
 ClaimsIdentity currentIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)currentPrincipal.Identity;

 currentIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Role2"));
```

Comment: Thx for your answer David, but it looks like as System.Web.Mvc.Controller.User has no public setter, so i can't apply new identity that way. Any suggestions what to do with the ClaimsPrincipal?

Comment: @milter, I update the code sample.  It always helps actually having an ide to write this stuff.  Hope it helps!